# Register a Facebook user on Parse

Tags: java, curl, web-applications, parse-platform, facebook-access-token

I'm implementing facebook login on my webapp.

I receive the access token, I know the email and everything is fine.
But I can't register the user on Parse database.

I made a java bean which has userId, userName, userEmail and token.
I put these in a form, that should be sent to Parse.

```
   /*--------------------------FORM FACEBOOK ----------------------------*/
        final TextField<String> userId = new TextField<>("userId");
        final TextField<String> userName = new TextField<>("userName");
        final TextField<String> userEmail = new TextField<>("userEmail");
        final TextField<String> token = new TextField<>("token");

        model = new CompoundPropertyModel<>(new FacebookLoginForm());
        form = new Form<FacebookLoginForm>("tokenForm", model)
        {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit()
            {
                ParseUser pu = new ParseUser();
                pu.setUsername(model.getObject().getUserName());
                pu.setEmail(model.getObject().getUserEmail());
                /*METHOD FOR PARSE*/
                curlParse(model.getObject().getToken(), model.getObject().getUserId()); 

            }
        };
        add(form);

        form.add(userId);
        form.add(token);
        form.add(userName);
        form.add(userEmail);
```

Parse curlParse():

```
public void curlParse(String token, String id)
{
    try
    { Date exp = new Date();
    exp.setTime(exp.getTime()+7200000);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss.SSS'Z'"); /*2012-02-28T23:49:36.353Z Data format*/
        String sExp = sdf.format(exp);
        Request.Post("https://api.parse.com/1/users")
                .addHeader("X-Custom-header", "stuff")
                .bodyString(
                        "{"
                        + " \"authData\": { "
                        + "  \"facebook\": {"
                        + " \"id\": \""+ id +"\","
                        + "\"access_token\": \""+ token +"\","
                        + " \"expiration_date\": \""+sExp+"\""
                        + " }"
                        + "}"
                        + "}", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON
                )
                .execute().returnContent().asString();
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Login2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    }
```

Since I need an absolute path to login user via facebook, I cannot use debug and there aren't any exceptions in the log(Tomcat) file. 
I tried to translate from the cURL to java, but it doesn't seem to work.
Where is my mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On html

```
<form id="tokenForm" wicket:id="tokenForm" >
         <input type="text" id="token" wicket:id="token" name="token"/>
         <input type="text" id="userId" wicket:id="userId" name="userId"/>
         <input type="text" id="userName" wicket:id="userName" 
         <input type="text" id="userEmail" wicket:id="userEmail" name="userEmail"/>
         <input type="submit"id="facebookSubmit" wicket:id="facebookSubmit" name="facebookSubmit">
</form>
```

On js:

```
       function login() {
            openFB.login(
                    function (response) {
                        if (response.status === 'connected') {
                            getInfo();
                            document.getElementById("token").value = response.authResponse.token;

                        } else {
                            alert('Facebook login failed: ' + response.error);
                        }
                    }, {scope: 'email'});
        }


        function getInfo() {
            openFB.api({
                path: '/me',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    document.getElementById("userId").value = data.id;
                    document.getElementById("userEmail").value = data.email;
                    document.getElementById("userName").value = data.first_name;
                    document.getElementById("userSurname").value = data.last_name;
                    document.getElementById("facebookSubmit").click();
                },
                error: errorHandler});
        }
```

on java:

```
public void curlParse(String token, String id)
    {

        try
        {
            Date exp = new Date();
            exp.setTime(exp.getTime() + 7200000);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"); /*2012-02-28T23:49:36.353Z */

            String sExp = sdf.format(exp);
            String resp = Request.Post("https://api.parse.com/1/users")
                    .addHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", CWSApplication.getParseDotComApplicationID())
                    .addHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", CWSApplication.getParseDotComApplicationKey())
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .bodyString(
                            "{"
                            + " \"authData\": { "
                            + "  \"facebook\": {"
                            + " \"id\": \"" + id + "\","
                            + "\"access_token\": \"" + token + "\","
                            + " \"expiration_date\": \"" + sExp + "\""
                            + " }"
                            + "}"
                            + "}", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON
                    )
                    .execute().returnContent().asString();

            /*System.out.println(ResponseParse);*/
            CWSSession session = (CWSSession) getSession();
            ParseUser loggedUser = new ParseUser();
/*questo con la libreriagson ci legge il JSON che ha i dati che ci servono da mettere su Parse*/
            try
            {
                JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(resp));

                reader.beginObject();

                while (reader.hasNext())
                {

                    String name = reader.nextName();

                    if (name.equals("objectId"))
                    {
                        loggedUser.setObjectId(reader.nextString());

                    } else if (name.equals("sessionToken"))
                    {
                        loggedUser.setSessionToken(reader.nextString());

                    } else
                    {
                        reader.skipValue(); //avoid some unhandle events
                    }
                }

                reader.endObject();
                reader.close();

            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```